# does not contain a definition for 'DropDownList'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

UPDATE:

since its my `DropDownTypes` is a collection so I try to pass something like this: it works but the only problem i'm having is that its selecting the default value which is whatever the index of 0 and my `item.Type` is the selected value

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => item.Type, new SelectList(item.DropDownTypes.Select(x => x.Text)))
```

What I'm doing wrong here, I'm trying to load the dropdownlist

> 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper>'
>   does not contain a definition for 'DropDownList' and the best
>   extension method overload
>   'System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownList(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,
>   string,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable,
>   object)' has some invalid arguments

```
@model IEnumerable<web.Models.CollectionViewModel>
@foreach (var item in Model )
{
  <tr>
    <td>
         @Html.DropDownList(item.DropDownTypes, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.DropDownLoadRecoveryType, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </td>
  </tr>
}
```

Comment: You have a number of issues - you cant use `DropDownListFor()` in a loop unless you generate a new `SelectList` and set the selected value in each iteration, or use a custom `EditorTemplate` for the model and pass a `SelectList` as additional view data. Can you post the model and the GET method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I was able to achieve a resolution, in case anybody else needs to know.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => item.Type.Value, new SelectList(ViewBag.DropDownLoadRecoveryType,  "Value", "Text", item.Type))
```

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of the [`DropDownList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470380(v=vs.118).aspx) helper that you are using must be a string so make sure that `item.DropDownTypes` is actually a string. If it isn't you might consider calling `.ToString()` on it.

Comment: I'm looking into it now and my `item.DropDownTypes` is a collection so even if I used `DropdownlistFor`

Answer (score 0):

You should consider adding the selected value of the dropdown list into another variable on your model. That way you can use it in the dropdown list as you're passing a list at present which isn't valid:

```
@model IEnumerable<web.Models.CollectionViewModel>
@foreach (var item in Model )
{
  <tr>
    <td>
         @Html.DropDownList(item.SelectedDropDownType, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.DropDownLoadRecoveryType, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </td>
  </tr>
}
```

Where `item.SelectedDropDownType` could be

```
public string SelectedDropDownType { get; set;}
```

Comment: yes I have tried so what is happening now that all the dropdownlist is getting the same text which is index of 0, even though my id is different

Comment: I have updated my question, please have a look at it.